# Make prints of mpiexec arguments rather than the arguments of the program being executed

Tags: c, mpi, argv, argc

Why does the following code, compiled with `mpicc` and executed with `mpiexec -n 4 prg` prints *prg* and not *mpiexec*. How can I make my program print *mpiexec* ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("Command executed : %s\n",argv[0]);
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  /* some code */
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Short (and only) answer is: You can't. Because your program *isn't* `mpiexec`.

Comment: Call your called program "mpiexec", too. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to print the command line that executed my program `prg`.

Comment: @ThomasGuenet The misunderstanding is, that your program `prg` _was not_ executed by a command line, but by another program: mpiexec. But in many cases, if you give a broader context of what you are trying to do, someone might come up with a solution

Comment: @Ctx, OK I understand that thank, but as a consequence I do not understand what is the point to pass `NULL` or `&argv` parameters to `MPI_Init`... I thought that `MPI_Init(&argc,&argv)` was the function to use to have `argv[0]` equals `prg` rather than `mpiexec`.

Comment: `MPI_Init(&argc, &argv)` might use and trim some parameters that should be only used by the MPI library and not by the end user application. that is why these parameters are passed to `MPI_Init()`

Comment: @ThomasGuenet depending on the MPI implementation you use, there might be general mpi options which can be used and interpreted. See for example https://www4.cs.fau.de/Lehre/WS99/V_PPS/mpich/www3/MPI_Init.html. But for OpenMPI: `Open MPI accepts the C/C++ argc and argv arguments to main, but neither modifies, interprets, nor distributes them`

Comment: **WHY** do you want your program to behave like that? What are you **actually** trying to achieve?

Comment: @Zulan I just want my program `prg` to print in stdout how it was called. **Nothing else, as simple as that**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to tell *how your binary was called* (in a general, portable way). MPI offers no way to determine that. Even `mpiexec` itself is only loosely specified.

It's generally impossible even without MPI and multiple systems being involved. `prg` could have been called in any number of ways such as:

```
/bin/env prg
bash -c 'prg'
./my_prg_wrapper.sh
x='() { :;}; prg'
```